# jscrollpane - Change width of scroll bar handle?

Tags: jquery-plugins, width, jquery-jscrollpane

How can I change the width of the scroll bar (.jspDrag) for the jscrollpane jquery plugin?

If I set the width with css !important then the scroll bar does get smaller, but so does the length of the area you can drag it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was being blind:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/drag_size.html